# Attempting to pull access form information into table with SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Currently, I am attempting to make a query that pulls the user's entry from an MS Access form and puts that entry into a table for later usage. This is what I have come up with so far, but I can't get it to save so hopefully this is either correctable or there is a different approach to this problem.

```
INSERT INTO tempOrder ('ProductID')
VALUES(

SELECT ProductID
FROM Product
WHERE ProductName is FORMS!Sandwich!sandwichChoice1
);
```

Answer (score 1):

for insert select you should use

```
  INSERT INTO tempOrder (ProductID)
  SELECT ProductID  
  FROM Product
  WHERE ProductName =  FORMS!Sandwich!sandwichChoice1
```

and use = for compare